# Plutus Playground: error evaluating 'hello, world' example

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, plutus-playground

When I try to evaluate the "Hello, world" example at https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/, I get the following error:
*DecodingError: An error occurred while decoding a JSON value: Under 'EvaluationResult': At object key 'emulatorLog': Under 'Array': At array index 0: Under 'EmulatorTimeEvent': At object key '_eteEvent': Under 'EmulatorEvent'': At object key 'contents': Under 'ChainEvent': At object key 'contents': At array index 2: Under 'Tx': At object key 'txData': Expected value of type 'Object'.
Please try again or contact support for assistance.*

Any idea?

Comment: it's a known issue: https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/issues/195

Comment: since you have the answer you can post it as an answer to your own question here. Perfectly legitimate practice in Stack Exchange, and you get more rep :)

Comment: @MatthewCapps, thanks for a hint

Answer (score 1):

This issue is reported at github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/issues/195

Please have a look at Starter Pack (https://docs.google.com/document/d/13112LHG9vVvNUs40oZSqZ-DF6_yFiT_SJZ2NaEmjMM4) for the steps to set up a local instance of Plutus Playground.